# Birds Problem-Brain Teaser- Amazon interview question

Tags: probability, puzzle

Three people consider as A,B,C went for sight seeing.

A,B and C each individually saw a bird that no other saw.(Eg: If A saw a bird the same is not seen by B and C)

Each pair saw a yellow bird that the other pair dint see(Eg: If AB saw a bird the same is not seen by BC and CA)

3 people together saw a yellow bird.


Question
Find the total number of birds and the number of yellow birds seen all together?

Comment: when you say that a group saw a bird (i.e. "a pair" or "all three"), do you mean that both members of the pair saw the bird, or **at least one** member of the pair saw the bird?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by the ambiguous phrasing, we could say that there are at least 3, 4 or 7 birds

Comment: As stated, there is no upper limit to the number of birds seen.

Comment: There are at least 7 birds, and at most infinity birds.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : yes, a pair means both the members in the group

Answer (score 3):

If I don't overlook any subtlety in the problem, in the minimal case, each bird determines a nonempty subset of $\{A,B,C\}$ (its obervers), hence there are at least $7$ birds, and at least $4$ of these are yellow.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree I  think only 6 birds are needed
A sees bird A not seen by B & C
B sees bird B not seen by A & C
C sees bird C not seen by A & B
A and B see yellow bird AB not seen by C
A and C see yellow bird AC not seen by B
B and C see yellow bird AC not seen by A

A, B and C have all seen a yellow bird (nowhere is written it has to be the same bird) 
so we are done.

If the birds A,B and C are all blue then  A, B and C have all seen a blue bird as well.

But they did go to the wrong place at a reasonable bird watching place you will see hundreds of birds.